# Semaphores in Ada

Tags: semaphore, ada

I have been given the following code and asked to implement a semaphore.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Id_Dispenser;
with Semaphores; use Semaphores;
procedure Philos is
 No_of_Philos : constant Positive := 5;
 Meditation : constant Duration := 0.0;
 type Table_Ix is mod No_of_Philos;
 Forks : array (Table_Ix) of Binary_Semaphore (Initially_Available => True);
 package Index_Dispenser is new Id_Dispenser (Element => Table_Ix);
 use Index_Dispenser;
 task type Philo;
 task body Philo is
  Philo_Nr : Table_Ix;
 begin
  Dispenser.Draw_Id (Id => Philo_Nr);
  Put_Line (“Philosopher” & Table_Ix’Image (Philo_Nr) & “ looks for forks.”);
  Forks (Philo_Nr).Wait; delay Meditation; Forks (Philo_Nr + 1).Wait;
  Put_Line (“Philosopher” & Table_Ix’Image (Philo_Nr) & “ eats.”);
  Forks (Philo_Nr).Signal; Forks (Philo_Nr + 1).Signal;
  Put_Line (“Philosopher” & Table_Ix’Image (Philo_Nr) & “ dropped forks.”);
 end Philo;
 Table : array (Table_Ix) of Philo; pragma Unreferenced (Table);
begin
 null;
end Philos;
```

The task requires a `Semaphores` package and a package `Id_Dispenser`. I am very new to Ada, but what is meant by a package? Does this mean both specification and body or just one, and how shall I go about implementing this?

Comment: Note: This code can potentially deadlock even if the semaphore is implemented correctly. This happens if every philosopher acquired the first fork and is waiting for the second fork. This situation is almost guaranteed to be encountered when you set `Meditation` to a value greater than `0.0`.

Comment: A package is Ada's name for a module. Modules provide encapsulation and information hiding, two of the big software-engineering concepts. Typically well designed modules implement an abstraction. The Ada package specification defines what the abstraction is and how a client uses it. The package body hides the implementation chosen for the abstraction. Often there is more than one way to implement an abstraction, and a module allows the choice of implementation to change without impacting the clients.

Comment: There is another clue here : `package Index_Dispenser is new Id_Dispenser (Element => Table_Ix);` This tells us that ID_Dispenser is not merely a package but a **generic package** which you can instantiate with different types including `Table_Ix` for Element. This exercise is asking you to learn about generics (in C++ terms, templates, but done right) as well as packages.

Comment: @BrianDrummond what features does Id_dispenser need to have?

Comment: Since the assignment requires the use of semaphores, you're stuck, but the correct way to approach the Dining Philosophers problem is with a special-purpose protected object that allocates both utensils for a philosopher at once, or notifies the the caller that that is not currently possible.

Comment: Apparently, Id_dispenser needs to implement a Draw_ID method. Possibly also an object factory to initialise Dispenser (whose declaration seems to be missing).

Answer (score 2):

> What is meant by a package?

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62987093/230513), an Ada *package* provides for [*modular programming*](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/modular_programming.html#modular-programming) to support encapsulation.

> The task requires a `Semaphores` package.

To this end, Ada offers [protected types](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p1-2.html#9) "which encapsulate and provide synchronized access to the private data of objects of the type without the introduction of an additional task." Additional discussion and examples may be found [here](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-9.html#1).

In the context of the [dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem), this complete [example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Style_Guide/Portable_Dining_Philosophers_Example) is worth reading; it is included in the [GNAT community edition](https://www.adacore.com/community) in `share/examples/gnat/simple_project`. In particular, the `package Chop` exports `protected type Stick`; each instance of `Stick` has an `entry Pick_Up` and `procedure Put_Down`. The `package Room` can then hold an array of utensils available to the diners, corresponding to `Forks` in your fragment.

```
Sticks : array (Table_Type) of Chop.Stick;
```

Answer (score 2):

As to "what is a package", check out the [Packages section in the Ada Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Packages).

All packages have a specification part. Most also have a body (and if the spec promises one, for example by declaring a subprogram, there must actually be one).

You can find discussion of implementing a semaphore in the Wikibook [section on Tasking](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Tasking#Protected_types), including code for a `Semaphore_Protected_Type`.

In your case, you need

```ada
package Semaphores is
   protected type Binary_Semaphore (Initially_Available : Boolean) is
      entry Wait;
      procedure Signal;
   private
      Available : Boolean := Initially_Available;
   end Binary_Semaphore;
   ...
end Semaphores;
```

Comment: @Ben: Compare `package Semaphores`, above, to `package Chop`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63443541/230513).