# Is there an Ada function similar to GotoXY?

Tags: ada

In Pascal there is a GotoXY function which positions the cursor at coordinates (X,Y) on the current window. Is there a similar function for Ada on Linux? I have found one for Win32 called NT_console, but nothing for Linux. More generally, is there any package which is similar to the crt unit on pascal? Thanks.

Comment: The example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63443541/230513) includes a simple ANSI terminal emulator and text window manager.

Comment: If you're OK with using ANSI, there's this Ada package: https://github.com/mosteo/ansi-ada

Answer (score 4):

There’s [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) (or, if instead you wanted a Windows solution, [JEWL](http://archive.adaic.com/tools/bindings/JEWL/jewl.html)). I’ve never used either of them, though.

Comment: I looked at porting JEWL to Linux once : didn't look trivial, but possibly worthwhile if enough people would use it. In any case I think the OP wants terminal console control, so NCURSES is  probably the answer. (In my position it was easier to roll my own following the crude Pascal solution, than find it!)

Comment: JEWL is a library for making windows, menus, etc., on MS Windows. No console stuff for Linux...

Comment: @Zerte Oh, OK, will amend

Comment: Thx! Since we are in the MS Windows digression, I'd recommend GWindows ( https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnavi/ ) which is much more complete than JEWL.

Answer (score 2):

Not as such.

But here's a "terminal" package I put together when porting a Pascal program that did some interactive text editing, originally on a Windows  CMD window ... actually, probably originally on DOS.

Incomplete, but maybe useful as a starting point. GotoXY is Set_Cursor here. Note the "atr" arguments on Clear_Scrn etc are ignored : this was good enough for my purpose : they could be removed (further simplifying the library) but were left for compatibility with the original project.

Works on a Debian Linux "Gnome Terminal" console but easily modified for other terminal types using escape sequences.

terminal.ads...

```
PACKAGE Terminal IS

TYPE WORD IS MOD 2**16;

   -- returned by Read_Special which reads the keyboard. Parse these
   -- if you need to interactively move round the screen, and get_cursor
   -- and set_cursor accordingly. Or if between space and tilde, 
   -- call LOBYTE to extract the (Ada.Characters.Latin_1) character.
   up_arrow    : CONSTANT WORD := 16#5B41#; 
   dn_arrow    : CONSTANT WORD := 16#5B42#;
   lf_arrow    : CONSTANT WORD := 16#5B44#;
   rt_arrow    : CONSTANT WORD := 16#5B43#;
   pgup        : CONSTANT WORD := 16#357E#;
   pgdn        : CONSTANT WORD := 16#367E#;
   F2          : CONSTANT WORD := 16#4F51#;
   F3          : CONSTANT WORD := 16#4F52#;
   F4          : CONSTANT WORD := 16#4F53#;
   ins         : CONSTANT WORD := 16#327E#;
   Esc         : CONSTANT WORD := 16#001B#;
   cr          : CONSTANT WORD := 16#000D#;
   lf          : CONSTANT WORD := 16#000A#;   -- accept cr or lf for Linux too
   plus        : CONSTANT WORD := 16#002B#;
   minus       : CONSTANT WORD := 16#002D#;
   period      : CONSTANT WORD := 16#002E#;
   naught      : CONSTANT WORD := 16#0030#;
   nine        : CONSTANT WORD := 16#0039#;
   bcksp       : CONSTANT WORD := 16#007F#;   -- Gnome terminal "profile preferences" ... 
                                              -- backspace generates ASCII DEL (vs ctrl-H 0008)
   space       : CONSTANT WORD := 16#0020#;   -- {first printable character}
   tilda       : CONSTANT WORD := 16#007E#;   -- {last printable character}


FUNCTION LOBYTE(Data : WORD) RETURN CHARACTER;

PROCEDURE read_special(incode: OUT WORD); -- EXTERN;  
  -- {Reads special keyboard characters; LOBYTE(incode)= ASCII 
  -- HIBYTE(incode) = special code;}

PROCEDURE set_cursor(row, col: INTEGER); -- EXTERN; 
  -- {Sets screen cursor at line = row, column = col}

PROCEDURE get_cursor(row, col: OUT INTEGER); -- EXTERN;
  -- {Gets current cursor position: line = row, column = col}

PROCEDURE backspace;

PROCEDURE clear_scrn(atr: INTEGER); -- EXTERN;
  -- {Clears active display screen, sets display attribute}

PROCEDURE clear_ln(row, atr: INTEGER); -- EXTERN;
  -- {Clears single line row on active display screen, sets display attribute;

PROCEDURE scrlup_scrn(topln, botln, atr: INTEGER); -- EXTERN;
PROCEDURE scrldn_scrn(topln, botln, atr: INTEGER); -- EXTERN;
  -- {Scroll active display screen up or down one line in window defined by
  -- topln and botln; sets display attribute of blank line; }

END Terminal;
```

terminal.adb

```
WITH Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
WITH Ada.Text_IO; USE Ada.Text_IO;
WITH Ada.Integer_Text_IO; USE Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
WITH Ada.Characters.Latin_1;

PACKAGE BODY Terminal IS


FUNCTION LOBYTE(Data : WORD) RETURN CHARACTER IS
  TYPE BYTE IS MOD 2**8;
  FUNCTION Byte_To_Char IS NEW Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(BYTE,CHARACTER);
  Temp : BYTE := BYTE(Data MOD 2**8);
BEGIN
  RETURN Byte_To_Char(Temp);
END LOBYTE;

PROCEDURE read_special(incode: OUT WORD) IS 
  -- {Reads special keyboard characters; LOBYTE(incode)= ASCII 
  -- HIBYTE(incode) = special code; 
  temp1,temp2,tempx : CHARACTER := Ada.Characters.Latin_1.NUL;
  avail : BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    get_immediate(Standard_Input, temp1); -- block until input
    incode := Word(Character'pos(temp1));
    get_immediate(Standard_Input, temp2, avail); -- check for sequences
    IF avail THEN
      LOOP
        get_immediate(Standard_Input, tempx, avail);
        EXIT WHEN NOT avail;
        temp1 := temp2;
        temp2 := tempx;
      END LOOP; -- keep the last 2 characters of the sequence
      incode := Word(Character'pos(temp1) * 256 + Character'pos(temp2));
    END IF;
END read_special;

PROCEDURE set_cursor(row, col: INTEGER) IS
  -- {Sets screen cursor at line = row, column = col; }
  r0,r1,r2,c0,c1 : CHARACTER;
BEGIN
  r0 := Character'val( Character'pos('0') + (row + 1) MOD 10);
  r1 := Character'val( Character'pos('0') + ((row + 1) / 10) MOD 10);
  r2 := Character'val( Character'pos('0') + ((row + 1) / 100) MOD 10);
  c0 := Character'val( Character'pos('0') + (col + 1) MOD 10);
  c1 := Character'val( Character'pos('0') + ((col + 1) / 10) MOD 10);
  Put(Ada.Characters.Latin_1.ESC & '[' & r2 & r1 & r0 & ';' & c1 & c0 & 'H');
END set_cursor;

PROCEDURE get_cursor(row, col: OUT INTEGER) IS
  -- {Gets current cursor position: line = row, column = col}
BEGIN
  row := INTEGER(Ada.Text_IO.Line) - 1;
  col := INTEGER(Ada.Text_IO.Col) - 1;
END get_cursor;

PROCEDURE backspace IS
BEGIN
  Put(Ada.Characters.Latin_1.ESC & '[' & 'D');  -- Backspace
END backspace;

PROCEDURE clear_scrn(atr: INTEGER) IS
  -- {Clears active display screen, sets display attribute}
  -- row,col : INTEGER;
BEGIN
  Put(Ada.Characters.Latin_1.ESC & '[' & '2' & 'J');    
END clear_scrn;

PROCEDURE clear_ln(row, atr: INTEGER) IS
  -- {Clears single line row on active display screen, sets display attribute;
BEGIN
  set_cursor(row, 0);
  Put(Ada.Characters.Latin_1.ESC & '[' & '2' & 'K');    
END clear_ln;

PROCEDURE scrlup_scrn(topln, botln, atr: INTEGER) IS
  -- {Scroll active display screen up or down one line in window defined by
  -- topln and botln; sets display attribute of blank line}
BEGIN
  Put(Ada.Characters.Latin_1.ESC & '[' & '1' & 'S');    
END scrlup_scrn;

PROCEDURE scrldn_scrn(topln, botln, atr: INTEGER) IS
BEGIN
  Put(Ada.Characters.Latin_1.ESC & '[' & '1' & 'T');
END scrldn_scrn;

END Terminal;
```

Terminal escape sequences documented [here for example](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/4-console_codes/)

Comment: Thanks Brian! I'll give it a try.