# What is the non-synchronized equivalent to a protected type in Ada?

Tags: oop, ada, language-design

Ada has a construct called "protected types", where you have a collection of variables and subprograms associated with a type, and the subprograms have implicit synchronization. These types can be instantiated and each instance will have its own memory where the variables live. This looks a lot like the class/object duality in mainstream OOP languages such as C++ and Java, minus inheritance, plus mandatory implicit synchronization.

Is there an equivalent to this construct, minus the synchronization? If not, what's the rationale behind this design choice?

To be entirely clear, I'm aware that Ada supports different styles of OOP without any kind of synchronization. My question is about the specific style of OOP I mentioned - as it is one of the most common styles found in mainstream languages, and is indeed also present in Ada in some form.

To further clarify the question, which had been intentionally (and misguidedly) left open-ended, I am aware that the answer is "packages". But then, consider the following:

- We have packages, which are units containing variables and subprograms, of which several instances can be created
- We have types, which are enums or projections/mod of built-it types (I know this is a very approximate definition, specifics don't really matter here)
- We have protected types, which are... units containing variables and subprograms, of which several instances can be created. Plus, they have synchronization.

This begs the thought: why "protected types" and not "protected packages"? This thought is the origin of the present question.

Comment: @SimonWright thank you for specifying the reason for your vote. I'd like to add that through my own research effort I found multiple language constructs that might be used for OOP in Ada. Just not the specific style of it that we find in more modern languages, and in the protected type construct. My goal was to gain some insight from people who are expert on the topic, to then do some more focused research. As a Master student I really can't afford time for any more than that - and the alternative to asking experts for directions is learning only as much Ada as needed to pass my course.

Comment: @SimonWright you changed and then deleted your comment just as I published mine. For reference, Simon Wright's comment was about closing the question because it lacks own research and is off-topic.

Comment: You should change "modern OOP languages" for "other OOP languages", because Ada is no older than C++ and it is OOP since the 95 edition. Regarding the question, you should take a look to "tagged types", which enable full OOP programming, just the syntax will be unusual to you, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: @Gneuromante I will think about your suggested edit; I'm not entirely sold on your argument. As for tagged types, I'm aware of them. That's why my question is so specific. I'm aware that Ada supports OOP; and as far as I can see, different flavors of it. My question is about why one such flavor - which happens to be the most supported flavor in mainstream languages (maybe after "C style" oop, if you want to go there) - is only supported in conjunction with synchronization. I will edit the question to further clarify that.

Comment: @Gneuromante I have changed "modern OOP languages" to "mainstream OOP languages". I see your point but I think it's still appropriate to characterize the languages I'm talking about in some way more than "other".

Comment: See also this comparison of Ada [_packages_](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/Ada_For_The_CPP_Java_Developer/chapters/07_Packages.html#packages) with respect to the other languages mentioned; the rationale for _protected types_ is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63443541/230513) and referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63447784/230513).

Comment: @rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr Can you be more specific why you believe tagged types do not fit the construct.  They meet all of the requirements you specified.  They have a collection of variables and subprograms associated with the type.  They can be instantiated and each instance will have its own memory where the variables live.

Comment: Note that Ada was the first ISO-standard language with programming by type extension (often mistakenly referred to as OOP).

Comment: @Jere The point is a specific style/flavour - not the functionality. If the matter was just that of functionality, then every single language who has some kind of record/struct type thing would "support OOP".

Comment: Back in the day, this question would have been closed for not being about a programming/coding problem. I (wrongly) reacted in that light; we were always less critical in [ada], and now things are much more open.

Comment: @rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr Okie dokie!  Your first paragraph goes into those requirements I mentioned and the followup question after asks if there is an equivalent construct to the first paragraph.  Tagged types would be the answer to that part.  To the style side of the question.  Keep in mind that both Ada and C started early and morphed separately.  Ada 95 was derived from Ada83 and C++ was derived from C.  Two very different groups of people trying to tackle the same idea different ways at around the same time.  Also there wasn't an ISO OOP language available in 95 as C++ standardized in 98

Answer (score 3):

OOP is a set of concepts in programming without any dependence in a particular syntax. According to the [Ada 95 Rationale](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p1-2.html#1): "Type extension in Ada 95 builds upon the existing Ada 83 concept of a derived type. In Ada 83, a derived type inherited the operations of its parent and could add new operations; however, it was not possible to add new components to the type. The whole mechanism was thus somewhat static. By contrast, in Ada 95 a derived type can also be extended to add new components."

In Ada a type is a type, independently of it providing OOP features or not. Ada 95 provided extension on top of other POO features already provided by Ada 83 types. The advantage of that is that you can turn easily a non-tagged type to a tagged type, if you later need type-extension, without affecting current uses of the type. This also avoids introducing hidden features in the OOP syntax, like friend classes (types sharing the package), static members (global package variables), the implicit `this`, or `const` at the end of a method to indicate that `this` object is not modified, etc.

Why protected types do not follow this pattern? They probably follow that of Ada 83 task types, but the latter don't have a `private` part, so it is still inconsistent. The design probably chose syntax of task types as inspiration, but added private part for efficiency (that was the main concern: "protected types allows a more efficient implementation of standard problems of shared data access").

Answer (score 3):

So this is an answer to the title of this question:
"What is the non-synchronized equivalent to a protected type in Ada?"

I'm adding this mainly for people searching this question looking for the answer to the topic's title question.

Take a simple example protected type:

```ada
protected type My_Type is

    procedure Set_Value(Value : Integer);
    function Get_Value return Integer;
    
private

    The_Value : Integer := 0;
    
end My_Type;

protected body My_Type is

    procedure Set_Value(Value : Integer) is
    begin
        The_Value := Value;
    end Set_Value;
    
    function Get_Value return Integer is
    begin
        return The_Value;
    end Get_Value;
    
end My_Type;
```

The equivalent non synchronized version would be to use a record type (or a tagged record if you want type extension) within a package paired with the operations on that type:

```ada
package My_Types is 

    -- For type extension use:
    -- type My_Type is tagged private;
    type My_Type is private;
    procedure Set_Value(Self : in out My_Type; Value : Integer);
    function Get_Value(Self : My_Type) return Integer;
    
private

    -- For type extension use:
    -- type My_Type is tagged record
    type My_Type is record
        The_Value : Integer := 0;
    end record;
    
end My_Types;

package body My_Types is

    procedure Set_Value(Self : in out My_Type; Value : Integer) is
    begin
        Self.The_Value := Value;
    end Set_Value;
    
    function Get_Value(Self : My_Type) return Integer is
    begin
        return Self.The_Value;
    end Get_Value;
    -- Alternate syntax:
    -- function Get_Value(Self : My_Type) return Integer is (Self.The_Value);
    
end My_Types;
```

Operations declared within a package that operate on a type in the package before that type is [frozen](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/2xrm/html/RM-13-14.html) are **"associated"** to that type (Ada calls them [primitive operations](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/2xrm/html/RM-3-2-3.html)).  This includes functions that return those types.

For the "why" each layout was chosen differently, I don't really know.  It might be helpful to take a look at the bottom of the following page and look through all the comments/emails/discussions of the ARG (credit to Simon Wright for the initial link):

http://archive.adaic.com/standards/ada95.html

If I had to guess without fully reading those sections Simon pointed me to (I will get to reading them all the way through), I would wager it has to do with the fact that records existed as is before protected types existed and protected types were thought more of an extension of the tasking model, so they iterated on the task type layout for protected type.  Some of what I did read([here](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/95lsn/lsn-025.txt) and [here](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/95lsn/LSN1047.Protected.txt)) already led me to believe they ran into some existing issues (either technical or philosophical) trying to layout protected types more like records.

Note that protected types do not give the full set of "information hiding" capabilities as most programmers expect, such as public vs private member variables (only private for protected types).

Credit to Simon Wright for the links I provided

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to define a complete type (data + operations) is Ada is with a package containing the type declaration (often private) and the subprograms for the type.

In general, encapsulation and information hiding (package) are orthogonal to types and subprograms in Ada. In many commonly used languages, encapsulation and information hiding are provided only by the class construct.

Comment: Ok - so the package really _is_ the "basic" modularity construct in Ada. Then, if you care to add to your answer, this begs the question: why protected types and not protected packages? I.e. why, instead of extending packages with the concept of implicit synchronization they extended types, adding functionality similar to that of packages, plus synchronization?

Comment: @rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr Jeffrey covered it in that 2nd paragraph.  Ada makes a good faith effort to provide you the various aspects of programming as building blocks you can choose from and use independently.  Modularity and Synchronization are two very different unrelated things.  Ada provides them separately so you can manage them how you like.  It's very different from other languages that do a lot more of "if you want this feature, you need to also use this feature", such as needing classes for encapsulation in C++ and Java.  Encapsulation is very possible without type extension.

Comment: Ada 83 had task types, and Ada 95 added protected types along similar lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a ramble round the topic ...

If you had a `protected package`, what parts of its contents would be synchronised? Any variable, spec or body? any type? child packages? And, to be able to create multiple instances of the package, it’d have to be `generic`. How then could you create an instance within a record? I think it needs to be a type.

As I understand it, there’s not really a parallel to `package` in C++, so you’d have to say `protected class Foo ...` which seems hard to distinguish from a protected type.

Given packages, which already encapsulate everything else, I guess the design team could have gone with something like

```
type P is record
   ...
end record;
pragma Protected (P);
```

where primitive operations of `P` would be synchronised, but you then have the problem of clarity (primitiveness being easy to get wrong) and of visibility (you really don’t want any of the components of `P` being accessible from outside). What syntax do we use for `entry` operations? Protected types seem a reasonable compromise.

Comment: The closest parallel to a package in C++ would probably be a fully static class (static in C, not Ada).  A lot of people mistakenly compare it to namespaces, but there are more semantic crossovers with a fully static class.  You can even emulate child packages using additional nested inner classes which can be declared in separate files (though you still have to at least forward declare them in the parent).  It's not a perfect parallel though as the languages are very different.

Comment: On the entry question, one option might be to use the same syntax as procedure but with the entry keyword instead and the conditional as part of the specification.
entry My_Entry(Params : Params_Types) when Condition_True;
entry My Entry(Params : Params_Types) is
begin
   -- stuff
end My_Entry;

Comment: and an alternative design to protected types would be to treat the protected keyword the same as limited:  type My_Type is protected record -- stuff end record.  basically morph the style off of derived types instead of tasks.  Again, just an alternative thought.  Not sure if it is a great thought.  Could even be used in conjuction with tagged:  type My_Type is tagged protected record -- stuff end record;

Comment: Note that I am not advocating for the above.  Just thought streaming

Comment: You can see this alternate syntax might have had legs back in ’93 or so. I found Language Study Notes [here, still "protected record"](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/95lsn/lsn-025.txt) and  [here, now "protected type"](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/95lsn/LSN1047.Protected.txt) which shed a little light

Comment: Thanks Simon!  @rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr You might find the following page interesting as to the various thought processes put into Ada95, credit goes to Simon for pointing me towards it.  The bottom section has discussions/thoughts/notes on the various features such as protected types, tagged types, etc.:  http://archive.adaic.com/standards/ada95.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent to this construct, minus the synchronization?
> If not, what's the rationale behind this design choice?

Ok, the other answers are really quite good, but here's the simple answer:
Ada defines a “`type`” as *a set of values and a set of operations on those values*; the notion of “`subtype`” is likewise defined as *a type with an additional (possibly null) set of constraints on its values*. — This leads to the ability to say “*Subtype Natural is Integer 0..Integer'Last;*” — In Ada 83 there was no way to add values to a type, but there **was** type-derivation where you could 'inherit' a type, possibly adding other operations and/or altering representational items. (Thus you could have “`Type Native_Data is array(1..10, 1..200) of Integer;`” and “`Type External_Data is new Native_Data;`” with "`For External_Data'Convention use Fortran;`"<sup>1</sup> and convert between native and external formats via conversion: `Data:= Native_Data( From_Disk(File => "Import.dat") )`.)

So, Ada95 built atop type-derivation allowing more values which *are* the type-extension (as well as the more operations). — Ada95 also extended the library/compilation-units structure from a 'flat' notion to a hierarchical one, but the basic unit of organization was (and is still) the `package`.

Now, we get to `protected types`, protected types **are** synchronization types, the data encapsulated into the construct and manipulated via accessors and mutators — this construct is pretty much the bastard child of `packages` and `tasks`: it is structured reminiscent of the package and has the queue-like access (entries, functions. procedures) of tasks, albeit a bit more 'exposed'/explicit than the implicit nature of task entries and the rendezvous.

So then, what is a protected type without synchronization?
Simple, a regular type.

> This begs the thought: why "protected types" and not "protected
> packages"?

While I'm sure that the above provides enough information for you to suss things out, the simple answer is this:
Packages are really interfaces (in the general notion, not the keyword/tagged-type notion) and namespaces: they declare the public view and also segregate the private implementation, as well as encapsulating the scope of the things within.

Thus a “`Protected Package`” would essentially be the protected type "but with namespacing" — and thus be a really redundant construct, not to mention that one of the motivating factors for protected types was the ability to drop the active thread of control required from tasks for synchronization: all that can be handled by the compiler inserting the proper queuing/bookkeeping around accesses without any of the complexity (and timing/scheduling impositions) that a task would require — so there would have to be special rules for a "protected package" either disallowing `Task` or requiring some special form, which would add complexity to the compiler.

<sup>1</sup> — Fortran uses column-major ordering for its multidimensional arrays, Ada uses row-major ordering [I don't recall if this is required by the LRM]; this 'trick' allows you to have the compiler handle the "trans-positioning", as well as using the type-system to keep track of which is which. (You can use this with things like network-format vs native-format in protocols, too.)